# Pass file path to API without Escape Characters

Tags: c#, escaping, desktop-application, filepath, quickbooks

I am working on the `QuickBooks SDK` and have to pass the Company file path to the `OpenConnection` method of `QBSessionManager`. I have got the code working and I am able to access and use the QuickBooks data in my application. Now with QuickBooks SDK, if you pass the Company file path exactly the same as being used in the QuickBooks Application, you don't need the QuickBooks application to be open to access the data, if proper permission was granted to your application the first time. This is how I try to open the connection

```
sessionManager.OpenConnection(filepath, <app-name>);
```

I need to pass the filepath without escape characters to access the data without opening QuickBooks. As C# compiler is adding '\' as escape character, all the '\' in path are coming as `'\\'`, so the resultant string becomes alien for QuickBooks and it insists(Exception: Could not start QuickBooks) on opening the 
QuickBooks application.
I have tried replacing `'\\'` to '\', but the resultant string will always have the escape character.
I also tried to pass a verbatim hard-coded path like:

```
sessionManager.OpenConnection(@"E:\123\123.QBW", <app-name>);
```

but of no avail.
Can you please guide me on how to pass the filepath without escape character?
PS: I am getting the file path from `OpenFileDialog`. And all the Double-Slashes had to be codified in this question too. :)

Comment: Maybe a URL style will work (work on system level file open) => "file://e:/123/123.qbw"

Comment: If you pass in @"E:\123\123.QBW" or "E:\\123\123.QWB",  OpenConnection method will receive the string without any escape characters as "E:\123\123.QWB"... In what format does the SDK expect the filepath to be?